# PHP & Excel, get data from Pivot Table into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, excel

I have been searching EVERYWHERE for the last 3 days.  I am going to start using an API that will pull down reports, but those reports are all pivot table based, with hidden data in the background.

I need to pull all the data from the Pivot Tables' hidden sheets that have the raw data, and put it into a MySQL database, is this even possible yet?

I have done CSV, and XML to MySQL using PHP, but I have never done Excel.

Thanks in advance, I hope that it is possible!

Comment: Do a google search on "apache poi".  It includes a java class that enables developers to read excel files.  If I can use this class with ColdFusion, you should be able to use it with php.

Comment: Unhide the hidden sheets and save as CSV?

Comment: You can set up CSV files as a source to feed PowerPivot, then from PowerPivot feed data into Pivot tables report.